# NullPointerException ao inserir data java

Tags: java, postgresql

Oi, eu já pesquisei em vários fóruns, youtube e google afora... preciso muito de ajuda pois tenho pouca experiência mas quero muito aprender, em muitas coisas eu consigo fazer mas quando é para datas dá uma travada...

o erro é esse...

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at dao.OrigemDAO.inserir(OrigemDAO.java:29)
>     at telas.TelaCadastroOrigem.bSalvarActionPerformed(TelaCadastroOrigem.java:151)
>     at telas.TelaCadastroOrigem.access$000(TelaCadastroOrigem.java:12)
>     at telas.TelaCadastroOrigem$1.actionPerformed(TelaCadastroOrigem.java:51)
> ```

essa é a classe DAO

```
package dao;


import conexao.ConnectionFactory;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import modelo.Origem;

public class OrigemDAO {

    String sql = null;
    Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    Statement declaracao;
    ResultSet resultado;

public void inserir(Origem o) {
        sql = "INSERT INTO origem (codigo_origem, descricao_origem,data_cadastro, registro) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, o.getCodigoOrigem());
            ps.setString(2, o.getDescricao());
            ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(o.getDataCadastro().getTime()));
            ps.setInt(4, o.getRegistro());
            System.out.println("sql:"+sql);

            ps.executeUpdate();


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Origem inserida com sucesso!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao inserir origem!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void atualizar(Origem o) {
        sql = "UPDATE origem SET codigo_origem = ?, descricao_origem = ?, data_cadastro = ?, "
                + " registro = ?, saldo=? WHERE id = ?";

        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setInt(1, o.getCodigoOrigem());
            ps.setString(2, o.getDescricao());
            ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(o.getDataCadastro().getTime()));
            ps.setInt(4, o.getRegistro());
            System.out.println(ps.toString());
            ps.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Origem atualizada com sucesso!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao atualizar origem!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void excluir(Origem o) {
        sql = "DELETE FROM origem WHERE id = ?";

        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, o.getId());

            ps.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Origem excluída com sucesso!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao excluir origem!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Origem> listar() {
        ArrayList<Origem> origens = new ArrayList<>();
        sql = "SELECT * FROM origem";

        try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultado = st.executeQuery(sql);

            while (resultado.next()) {
               int id = resultado.getInt("id");
               int codigo_origem = resultado.getInt("codigo");
               Date data_cadastro = resultado.getDate("data");
               String nome = resultado.getString("descricao");
               double saldo = resultado.getDouble("saldo");

                Origem origem = new Origem(/*id,codigo_origem,nome, data_cadastro, saldo*/);
                origens.add(origem);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao recuperar lista de origens!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return origens;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, a resposta está no próprio erro.

Seu objeto "o" está nulo.
**"o.getDataCadastro().getTime()"**
Você precisa verificar se o objeto "o" não está nulo e se existe dado no getDataCadastro(), caso contrário, irá ocorrer nullpointer.

É apenas isso, bastante simples.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigada vou testar agora mesmo e já posto...

Comment: ajudou sim, só não sei como passar o valor pra ele, é na classe dao mesmo ou pode ser da forma em que estou fazendo na tela pelo actionperformed?